# python - 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to decode the below from an aws kinesis data stream using aws lambda, but I keep getting a "'utf-8'** codec can't decode bytes in position 0-2: invalid continuation byte" error

```
x = b'\xf3\x89\x9a\xc2\n$dad568a5-6305-481c-b6f1-f8338cc127df\n$3d57f33a-d681-467b-bb82-89c0d77e2621\n$3ade7757-3df4-41ec-bdc8-52a27449c420\n$a0a59a4e-02f5-462d-8c3e-50030145cf17\x1a\x83\x01\x08\x00\x1a\x7f{ "window_start": "2022-12-30 13:25:00","window_end": "2022-12-30 13:35:00","player_id": 2004,"bonus_stake": 2.76,"bonus_win": 4}\x1a\x86\x01\x08\x01\x1a\x81\x01{"window_start": "2022-12-30 13:25:00","window_end": "2022-12-30 13:35:00","player_id": 2304,"bonus_stake": 2.2,"bonus_win": 2.21}\x1a\x87\x01\x08\x02\x1a\x82\x01{"window_start": "2022-12-30 13:25:00","window_end": "2022-12-30 13:35:00","player_id": 2290,"bonus_stake": 11.1,"bonus_win": 38.7}\x1a\x86\x01\x08\x03\x1a\x81\x01{"window_start": "2022-12-30 13:25:00","window_end": "2022-12-30 13:35:00","player_id": 2192,"bonus_stake": 1.32,"bonus_win": 0.6}\x10\xa6\x1a\tB\xa5\x9b\x14\xa5?\xad\xcd\x8b\xe8^\xcb'

s = x.decode()

print(s)
```

Comment: Is there a way to strip away all the data and just keep the data within the curly brackets including the curly brackets?

Comment: Where did that string come from? `chardet` thinks it's cp1254-encoded Turkish, but that's not correct either.

Comment: I'm using AWS studio notebook to populate the kinesis data stream




CREATE TABLE temp(
        `window_start` timestamp(3)
        ,`window_end` timestamp(3)
        ,`player_id` bigint
        ,`bonus_stake` decimal(19,8)
        ,`bonus_win` decimal(19,8)
)
WITH (
'connector' = 'kinesis',
'stream' = 'XXXX',
'aws.region' = 'XXXXXX',
'scan.stream.initpos' = 'LATEST',
'format' = 'json')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the decode of raw data from output stream fails is because aggregation is enabled by default when writing into Kinesis stream. You can set the following on your table

```
'sink.producer.aggregation-enabled' = 'false'
```